# Laravel 5.4 401/Unauthenticated using Passport and multiple token types

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, middleware, laravel-passport

The backstory on this, I have been working on the instructions from the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport

I have

1. Laravel 5.4
2. "laravel/passport": "^3.0" from composer
3. Local Mac osx running Mamp pro, Php  7.0.15

I am calling the sample user route in routes/api.php

```
Route::get('/user', function () {
    return 'testing';
})->middleware('auth:api');
```

Postman curl Header (pulled from the code export in Postman):

```
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "accept: application/json",
    "authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6ImM3ZmI2ZmNmMWFkOGQ0NjFkNTdhMWU2NjFiYjhhOThmOTJhOTBkMDFkNDkwZDFjNDRkNDg5MTdlYjJiZWYyMDlkNjNmOTQwMjIxNTljZWI5In0.eyJhdWQiOiIxIiwianRpIjoiYzdmYjZmY2YxYWQ4ZDQ2MWQ1N2ExZTY2MWJiOGE5OGY5MmE5MGQwMWQ0OTBkMWM0NGQ0ODkxN2ViMmJlZjIwOWQ2M2Y5NDAyMjE1OWNlYjkiLCJpYXQiOjE1MDE3OTQ2NjIsIm5iZiI6MTUwMTc5NDY2MiwiZXhwIjoxNTMzMzMwNjYyLCJzdWIiOiIxIiwic2NvcGVzIjpbImFwaS1hY2Nlc3MiXX0.CPGM4PIKJBeiJvokuDzShz_1CnqHlnFIML-tWoBCn5GcijMXmQkWOHzTI8QwTws2h719TGA4hemXDljjqoZB0LiztAx2JZ3OhjNS-MhrMNujnTJUbvkXAVfcRdybhlDEWof_iboLICQTYNTslX1iw-2DCyFMh8gB4INAKUhpvzA955ALB-ZunKrjSNKdRkgtZRe0t6VyJf9LwzgjIAfSKoi_qRis36KD7hcf0Id_iWZkhvS-ZfuM5eUpzUooUe0rb4rkYYEYndlHlY7-uuZPlzmPMpaJTR4AW1CLkaK5Ic7fde1x1kk2duW_Znd9ki2YBP0kw7ifAmg2DaM5r2-0kEx_1iFuCIxE8QJns1aIm3XjWoOApovt7V6-s3yJZK3xlIDCjFI-C59RHiVSabh-hKdX4elvSL9taSQyuramPZPpsne9SUh4KCWul0iHoNjFdFJEut_TUBWyUPtD3J7gg6P97uRS_THDAUHMo2UYVhlnu9PV8SvbvjGj3OeaaH7ZbzWQCYKbqsLZAZ2mnJlFhTMghbaC2s_MND1zlRm7w9btmihxVW714NUbH8UAwSvrtIYYQ0itevZ59TLiAXprjmjkhiFkrhdX4bUje4uNEbLYawkZI-1o82IExW9D8kCYpOWOZdWTCLgmaE2wXcf-DTCV-9vDWRAdX1YmP4JbRsc",
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW",
    "postman-token: 2ec7a2c8-3489-812d-4638-ebb7dc62aeb1"
  ),
```

I have 1 personal access token generated using the Vue Components

I have checked that i am setting the token expiration for 1 year and that is reflecting in the db.

My AuthServiceProvider.php

```
Passport::routes();

        // TODO MAKE THEM LAST A LONG TIME
        Passport::tokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addYears(20));//You can also use addDays(10)
        Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addYears(20));//You can also use addDays(10) 
        Passport::pruneRevokedTokens(); //basic garbage collector

        Passport::tokensCan([
            'api-access' => 'Access Complete API',
        ]);
```

My RouteServiceProvider.php (mapApiRoutes is called in the map function)

```
protected function mapApiRoutes()
    {
        Route::group([
            'namespace' => $this->namespace,
            'prefix' => 'api',
        ], function ($router) {
            require base_path('routes/api.php');
        });
    }
```

My Kernel.php route middleware

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
];
```

-- EDIT -- AFTER MORE RESEARCH

I am using postman to test out my api auth and get a 401 each time I try. I have tried Personal Access Client and Password Grant Client and both have the same issue. After looking at them both I realized that both use Authorization Bearer [token] format.

So I started Logging out in various files in Passport source.

In the TokenGuard.php

```
public function user(Request $request) {

    Log::info('TokenGuard: '. $request);

    if ($request->bearerToken()) {
        return $this->authenticateViaBearerToken($request);
    } elseif ($request->cookie(Passport::cookie())) {
        return $this->authenticateViaCookie($request);
    }
}
```

The Log looks like this:

```
[2017-08-10 20:50:20] local.INFO: TokenGuard 93: GET /api/user HTTP/1.1
Accept:          application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cache-Control:   no-cache
Connection:      keep-alive
Content-Type:    application/json
Host:            url.com:8888
Postman-Token:   66707fe5-8f6e-4920-948b-2804a76d4a65
User-Agent:      PostmanRuntime/6.2.5


[2017-08-10 20:50:20] local.INFO: TokenGuard 93: GET /api/user HTTP/1.1
Accept:          application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cache-Control:   no-cache
Connection:      keep-alive
Content-Type:    application/json
Host:            url.com:8888
Postman-Token:   66707fe5-8f6e-4920-948b-2804a76d4a65
User-Agent:      PostmanRuntime/6.2.5
```

The thing missing is the Bearer [token] portion of the request.  The TokenGuard code chunk is running an if/else.  This is where I think the failure is happening.

Shouldn't it be logging that out too? Since the Bearer Token is missing the If/Else fails and then it makes sense to return a 401.

Why would my Token be stripped out of the request.

Comment: How do you get your token in to JavaScript? The token in code sample above seems to be too long are you sure you did not copy-paste encrypted cookie instead?

Comment: When you create the personal access token the Vue component pops a modal that has the token in it.  I copied it and then used it.   I have tried this three separate times, to make sure I wasn't screwing that up.

Comment: Your only option is to debug this yourself, modify relevant files (even core Laravel ones) with `\Log::info...` statements and see yourself in what point you get stuck. Have fun!

Comment: @kyslik is there anything in my naming that is an issue?  like api vs auth:api or something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your `.htaccess`file under public directory of your project:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```